# Install older version of gnu-make in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnu-make

I want to install make 3.81 on Ubuntu 18.04.

So I download this version of make and run **./configure** and then **make**. But when compiling it gives me this error:

```
./glob/glob.c: In function ‘glob’:
./glob/glob.c:581:23: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘__alloca’; did you mean ‘alloca’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
       newp = (char *) __alloca (dirlen + 1);
                       ^~~~~~~~
                       alloca
./glob/glob.c:581:14: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
       newp = (char *) __alloca (dirlen + 1);
              ^
./glob/glob.c:709:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
        newp = (char *) __alloca (home_len + dirlen);
               ^
./glob/glob.c:732:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
        newp = (char *) __alloca (end_name - dirname);
               ^
./glob/glob.c:783:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
        newp = (char *) __alloca (home_len + rest_len + 1);
               ^
./glob/glob.c:814:11: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘__stat’; did you mean ‘__xstat’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         : __stat (dirname, &st)) == 0
           ^~~~~~
           __xstat
./glob/glob.c: In function ‘glob_in_dir’:
./glob/glob.c:1256:21: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    char *fullname = (char *) __alloca (dirlen + 1 + patlen + 1);
                     ^
./glob/glob.c:1283:12: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    names = (struct globlink *) __alloca (sizeof (struct globlink));
            ^
./glob/glob.c:1341:32: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
         struct globlink *new = (struct globlink *)
                                ^
./glob/glob.c:1367:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
       names = (struct globlink *) __alloca (sizeof (struct globlink));
```

Same situation at building version 3.82. My current version of make is 4.1.

Is anybody know what could be wrong?

Thanks

EDIT:

```
glob/libglob.a(glob.o): In function `glob_in_dir':
/opt/make-3.81/glob/glob.c:1361: undefined reference to `__alloca'
/opt/make-3.81/glob/glob.c:1336: undefined reference to `__alloca'
/opt/make-3.81/glob/glob.c:1277: undefined reference to `__alloca'
/opt/make-3.81/glob/glob.c:1250: undefined reference to `__alloca'
glob/libglob.a(glob.o): In function `glob':
/opt/make-3.81/glob/glob.c:575: undefined reference to `__alloca'
glob/libglob.a(glob.o):/opt/make-3.81/glob/glob.c:726: more undefined references to `__alloca' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:410: recipe for target 'make' failed
make[2]: *** [make] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/opt/make-3.81'
Makefile:603: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/make-3.81'
Makefile:326: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: You should ask this on the [Ask Ubuntu stackexchange](https://askubuntu.com/). While this is a build tool and sort of on topic, you might get a better response on install issues

Comment: just a guess, but seems likely that you're not including the right set of `.h` files. Sorry, no idea comes to mind to move  you forward. Search here and look at other `[make]` Qs? Good luck!

Comment: @scrappedcola Yeah I should ask there, don't know why it didn't comes to my mind :D

Comment: @shellter Well I just download their official source code and then try to compile like they said, so I don't think that problem is here. Anyway thank you and as you mention I will try to find something about it.

Comment: These are just warnings.  Do you actually get a compile error?  Does the `make` executable get generated, or not?  If it does, you're done, congratulations!  If it doesn't, you'll have to show us the _error_ messages that cause the compile to fail, not the warnings.

Comment: @MadScientist Errors should be in edited question and no unfortunately make isn't generated.

Comment: Solved by same [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062051/install-older-version-of-gnu-make-in-ubuntu-18-04) on AskUbuntu. Problem is described and solved in this [discussion](http://gnu-make.2324884.n4.nabble.com/undefined-reference-to-alloca-td18308.html)

Comment: As a last comment, why do you want 3.81? Build systems which rely on a specific older version of make are most often buggy or at least awkward themselves. Maybe easier to fix the build scripts than the tool.

Comment: @Vroomfondel I was compiling Android 4.3 on my old phone, which requires older make.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can try modify the `glob.c` file:

```
# if _GNU_GLOB_INTERFACE_VERSION == GLOB_INTERFACE_VERSION
```

to

```
# if _GNU_GLOB_INTERFACE_VERSION >= GLOB_INTERFACE_VERSION
```

For me it's work and i can build make 3.82

(credit: http://gnu-make.2324884.n4.nabble.com/undefined-reference-to-alloca-td18308.html)

Comment: (In version 4.2.1)This change is giving me a segmentation fault.
From http://gnu-make.2324884.n4.nabble.com/undefined-reference-to-alloca-td18308.html ,
Replace, 
#if !defined __alloca && !defined __GNU_LIBRARY__ 
with
#if !defined __alloca && defined __GNU_LIBRARY__

Comment: sed -i 's/# if _GNU_GLOB_INTERFACE_VERSION == GLOB_INTERFACE_VERSION/# if _GNU_GLOB_INTERFACE_VERSION >= GLOB_INTERFACE_VERSION/g' make-3.82/glob/glob.c

Answer (score 2):

**Using Lubuntu 20.04.4 64bit**

For me a working solution was:
Replace,

```
#if !defined __alloca && !defined __GNU_LIBRARY__
```

with

```
#if !defined __alloca && defined __GNU_LIBRARY__
```

by *underhood31*

and change

```
#ifndef __GNU_LIBRARY__
```

in:

```
#ifdef __GNU_LIBRARY__
```

to build without (critical!) warnings.

Comment: If portability is important, this fixes Ubuntu but breaks the builds on AIX, HP/UX, and Solaris.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in the make-3.82 directory.
Content from user:A2N aka ace2nutzer.

```bash
sed -i 's/#if !defined __alloca \&\& !defined __GNU_LIBRARY__/#if !defined __alloca \&\& defined __GNU_LIBRARY__/g; s/#ifndef __GNU_LIBRARY__/#ifdef __GNU_LIBRARY__/g' "./glob/glob.c"`
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).